# How to pass filepath properly into argparser for tesseract?

Tags: python, python-tesseract

I am following [this guide](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/) to do image analysis.

In the first block of code (lines 9-14) there is an option to input file path to the image. When I input my file and run lines 9-14 I keep getting the following error:

```
 SystemExit: 2

    usage:  [-h] -Users/bob/Desktop/image.png IMAGE
            [-p PREPROCESS]
    : error: argument -Users/bob/Desktop/image.png/--image is required
```

This is how I inputted my file path in line 10 of the guide.

```
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--Users/bob/Desktop/image.png", required=True,
    help="path to input image to be OCR'd")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--preprocess", type=str, default="thresh",
    help="type of preprocessing to be done")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the file path to get this error.

Comment: provide command input which you are passing to script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Appears to be a copy/paste mishap - the tutorial has `"--image"` while your snippet shows `"--Users/bob/Desktop/image.png"`, which looks like pasted text accidentally landing at the wrong place.